# Prove $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact in the Standard Topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact in the Standard Topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

**My proof:**

Assume $\mathbb{R}$ is compact in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Take any open cover of $\mathbb{R}$, says $(U_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$. As $\mathbb{R}$ is compact, there are $\alpha_i \in I$, $i=1,2, \cdots, n$ such that $\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}$.

*On the other hand, let $(-m_i, m_i)$ be an open set containing $U_{\alpha_i}$*, for all $i=1,2, \cdots , n$. Let $S=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$.

We have $\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i} \subset{(-S,S)}.$  (contradict because $S+1 \in \mathbb{R}$).

Thus $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact in the Standard Topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I'm not sure about my proof because of the italic line. Is my proof true? Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to just find an open cover of $\Bbb R$ which has no finite subcover. Something that comes to mind as something that could work is

$$\left\{ (-n,n) \middle| n \in \Bbb Z^+ \right\}$$

Comment: My teacher told me to do so and I've done it, but I'm trying to approach the problem using contradiction.

Comment: @RopuToran: Why? Exhibiting an open cover that has no finite subcover is the simplest, most satisfactory possible argument.

Comment: "On the other hand, let (−mi,mi) be an open set containing Uαi," There is utterly no reason to assume the $U_{\alpha_i}$ is contained in any open interval or that there is any $m_i$ so the $U_{\alpha_i}\subset (-m_i, m_i)$.  After all $\{(-\infty, 0), (-7,3), (0,\infty)\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb R$ and it is its own finite subcover.  $(-7,3)\subset (-7,7)$ that's okay but what about $(-\infty, 0) \in (-m_1, m_1)$.  What is your choice of $m_1$ for that.

Comment: Also you can't assume if $\mathbb R$ is not compact that every open cover will fail to have a finite subcover.  Some open covers will.  So assuming $U_\alpha$ is an open cover.  That only you will *NEVER* be able to prove $U_\alpha$ doesn't have a finite subcover because.... it might.